# Trying to create Palo Alto VM with Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, firewall, azure-virtual-machine

I'm currently trying to create a Palo Alto VM-Series firewall with Azure Powershell to later incorporate some changes.

I have the following relevant code

```
$VM = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName -Skus $skuName -Version "latest"

$VM = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize 

Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $VM -Publisher paloaltonetworks -Product vmseries1 -Name "bundle2" 

# Specify the OS disk name and create the VM
$DiskName='OSDisk-'+$VMName
$SA = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name $SAName -ResourceGroupName $RGName
$OSDiskUri = $SA.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $VMName+".vhd"
   $VM = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VM -Name $DiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage
$VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $VNIC01.Id -Primary
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Location $Region -VM $VM -Verbose
```

I get the error

```
New-AzureRmVM : Changing property 'osDisk.createOption' is not allowed.
ErrorCode: PropertyChangeNotAllowed
ErrorMessage: Changing property 'osDisk.createOption' is not allowed.
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: Conflict
OperationID : 882848ca-7053-4098-9599-d25d58b4b3fe
At C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\DeployMultipleNicPANWv0.2.ps1:192 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Location $Region -VM $VM -V ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

I had previously tried some changes since it tells me the origin vhd was created with Premium Storage and I have a Standard Storage.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, I found it the scripts contain

`“$VM = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VM -Name $DiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage”.`

And the error code is `409`. This issue may caused by this :`VM created from Image cannot have blob based disks. All disks have to be managed disks.`

So, you should decide what source do you want to use to create VM. If you just want to use image to create VM, you **should not add** `-VhdUri $OSDiskUri`

More about how to use image to create a new VM with Powershell, refer to [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed)

Also, you can use templates to create Palo Alto VM easily. More about  how to create Palo Alto VM with templates, refer to [this link](https://github.com/PaloAltoNetworks/azure/tree/master/vmseries-simple-template).

----------Update----------

Ensure your image and other requirements had properly been configured  ,and then you can use following Powershell scripts to create:

```
    $VM = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize 

    $VM = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName $pubName -Offer $offerName -Skus $skuName -Version "latest"

    Set-AzureRmVMPlan -VM $VM -Publisher paloaltonetworks -Product vmseries1 -Name "bundle2" 


    $VM = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VM -CreateOption fromImage -Caching ReadWrite
    $VM = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VM -Id $VNIC01.Id -Primary

    New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Location $Region -VM $VM -Verbose
```

NOTE: With managed disk, we cannot change OSdiskname when we use image or vdi to create VM. If you still  cannot create it, I suggest you use the templates to create it. Just click deploy on Azure and then supply required information.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now it shows me a 400 code error with New-AzureRmVM : Cannot specify user image overrides for a disk already defined in the specified image reference.
ErrorCode: InvalidParameter
ErrorMessage: Cannot specify user image overrides for a disk already defined in the specified image reference.
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : 86e4ff4c-c52c-472c-b14a-a09f924bc1ab

Comment: Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: HI,@OmarOchoa, well, I will test it and  follow your case.